# comapring two arrays and return the index of the common element in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays in php and i am using the array_intersect function to find the common elements and if common elements exists i want to display the index of theses common elements in the 1st array

here is what i have done so far..

```
  function check_if_exists($company_timings,$in_time)


   {    

     $length_of_company=sizeof($company_timings);
      $length_of_emp=sizeof($in_time);
       $common=array_intersect($company_timings,$in_time);
        $length_of_common=sizeof($common);
       $key=array_search($common,$company_timings);
      return $key;


    }
```

but its not return the keys there are common elements which are 09:00:00 and 11:00:00 and when i pass 11:00:00 rather than $common in array_search then it gives the accurate result other wise with the $common_array it doesn't work,,,kindly help me in ameliorating the code

Answer (score 0):

This function returns an array containing the common elements and their positions in both array, or `false`if no common elements are found :

```
function check_if_exists($arr1, $arr2) {
    $combined = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
    if (empty($combined))
        return false;
    $return = array();
    foreach ($combined as $elmt) {
        $return[$elmt] = array();
        $return[$elmt]['arr1'] = array_search($elmt, $arr1);
        $return[$elmt]['arr2'] = array_search($elmt, $arr2);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Test :

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$array2 = array('b', 'f', 'g', 'c');
$array3 = array('n', 'o', 'p', 'e');

$exists = check_if_exists($array1, $array2);
var_dump($exists);
$exists_no = check_if_exists($array1, $array3);
var_dump($exists_no);
```

Output :

```
array (size=2)
  'b' => 
    array (size=2)
      'arr1' => int 1
      'arr2' => int 0
  'c' => 
    array (size=2)
      'arr1' => int 2
      'arr2' => int 3

boolean false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with array_keys function

Here is an example code. Hope it will help you.

```
<?php
    $a =  array("a","b","c");
    $b =  array("c","d","a");
    $c =  array_keys(array_intersect($a,$b));
    var_dump($c);
?>
```